Magento 2 Customizable Options - generate always unique SKU
we are selling individually printed products in our Magento 2 instance.
Now I have set up an article in the way, that the print design name needs to be added by the client. See here:

But in our ERP sytem the articles at the moment alway arrive with the same SKU which is not unique.
Does anyone know how I could achieve a kind of dynamic SKU here? Means a date stamp or anything added to the SKU of products which are ordered as customizable products? Is it possible to use the SKU field in a dynamic way here?
I´d appreciate any hint on this.
Best regards
Ben
